# DoEvents delay varies for timer in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, doevents

I used DoEvents to provide a 1 second delay in the VBA execution, to display the countdown in timer properly. 
The code used was:

```
time2 = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Do Until Now >= time2
    DoEvents
Loop
```

I used the above code within another Do Until Loop. The code is showing the countdown, but the delay between each time slightly varies especially for the part displayed within the nested Do Until Loop!!

The rest of the code is:

```
Sub btnStart_Click()
 Dim time_2 As Variant
 g_position = True

 If g_position = True Then
    UserForm1.StartUpPosition = 0
    UserForm1.Left = Application.Left + 0.5 * Application.Width +    UserForm1.Width + 72
    UserForm1.Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (UserForm1.Height) - 36
 End If

 start = Now
 timeEnd = start + TimeValue("00:00:10")
 g_start = Format(start, "hh:mm:ss")
 g_timeEnd = Format(timeEnd, "hh:mm:ss")
 time_duration = timeEnd - start
 g_time_duration = Format(time_duration, "hh:mm:ss")
 Label1.Visible = True
 time_left.Caption = g_time_duration
 time_left.Visible = True
 btnStart.Visible = False
 time_2 = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
 Do Until Now >= time_2
    DoEvents
 Loop
 g_temp = Format(temp, "hh:mm:ss")
 etime = start + TimeValue("00:00:01")
 time_duration = timeEnd - etime
 g_time_duration = Format(time_duration, "hh:mm:ss")
 time_left.Caption = g_time_duration
 time_2 = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
 Do Until Now >= time_2
    DoEvents
 Loop
 Call modtimer.time_count(time_duration, etime, timeEnd, g_time_duration)

End Sub
```

The Module Code:

```
Sub time_count(time_duratn As Variant, etim As Variant, timEnd As Variant, g_time_duratn As Variant)

 temp_end = Format(TimeValue("00:00:00"), "hh:mm:ss")
 temp_alert = Format(TimeValue("00:00:05"), "hh:mm:ss")
 etim = etim + TimeValue("00:00:01")
 time_duratn = timEnd - etim
 g_time_duratn = Format(time_duratn, "hh:mm:ss")
 UserForm1.time_left.Caption = g_time_duratn
 time2 = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
 Do Until Now >= time2
    DoEvents
 Loop
 Do Until g_time_duratn = temp_end
    If g_time_duratn = temp_alert Then
        Beep
        MsgBox "Only 5 minutes remaining", vbInformation
    End If
    etim = etim + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    time_duratn = timEnd - etim
    g_time_duratn = Format(time_duratn, "hh:mm:ss")
    UserForm1.time_left.Caption = g_time_duratn
    time2 = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Do Until Now >= time2
        DoEvents
    Loop
 Loop
 End_Exam
End Sub
```

Why is the delay in the countdown varying? Can anybody help?

Comment: @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ's post summarise your current problem well. You can use `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))` as an alternative 1 sec delay solution.

Comment: @Tehscript: `Application.Wait` is only available in _Excel_, not in Word. Two workarounds are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50958119/9700298).

Answer (score 3):

You are getting different time spans because `Now`, as far as I tested, as 1 second resolution in Office VBA. So, `Now` will always round time to last second.

Eg, you start waiting at `00:00:00.500`, `Now` will return `#00:00:00#`. When time reach `00:00:01.000`, `Now` will return `#00:00:01#`, so you think you get 1 second delay, but it was just 0.5! Using `Now` you may "measure" 1 second time delays which may vary between 0 to 1 second!

As workaround, WinAPI `GetLocalTime` may be used to get 1 milisecond resolution timestamps:

```
Private Declare Sub GetLocalTime Lib "Kernel32" (lpSystemTime As Any)

Function Now_ms() As Date
    Dim st(0 To 7) As Integer
    GetLocalTime st(0)
    Now_ms = DateSerial(st(0), st(1), st(3)) + TimeSerial(st(4), st(5), st(6)) + st(7) / 1000# * #12:00:01 AM#
End Function
```

Replace `Now` with `Now_ms`, which is full compatible with `Date` data type and returns a better resolution timestamp (1ms).

Better resolution timestamps can be achieved using `GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime` (0.1μs) or `QueryPerformanceCounter`.

Comment: @LS_dev Thanks a lot, it worked!! I replaced Now with Now_ms as you said and it's showing the countdown properly.