# There is no Wait Method associated with Application in VisualBasic Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have VBA code to run a particular code and I am trying to pause the next execution by giving it a wait time of 3 seconds using the following line:

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
```

But I get the following error:

> Error: Method or data variable not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried `Excel.Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))` and it worked like a charm!

Comment: That's not Word though?

Comment: This will say "Variable not found"

Comment: Marking your own solution as the best whilst it is against your own question (asked about Word, answered in an Excel manner where the command .Wait is available as opposed to Word) 

Answer (score 8):

It is best to use External Library references (Early Binding) while developing your code.  Early Binding has the advantages of both intellisense and Help documentation.  A major disadvantage of Early Binding is that it requires the reference to be updated if a different version of the library is installed.  This is way it is best to remove the external references and convert code to Late Binding before distributing it.

Late binding uses `CreateObject` to import and instantiate a class object.

```
CreateObject("Excel.Application").Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
```

Alternatively, you could reference the WinApi `Sleep` function.

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

Usage:

```
 Sleep 3000 '3000 Milliseconds = 3 second delay
```

Comment: Application.Wait is not the same as Sleep! With Sleep, the application will freeze for that amout of time (usually a very short delay, as otherwise the application seems to be not responding any more), while Wait allows events (like hitting ESC to abort) to be recognized.

Comment: Good point @TomStein.

Answer (score 3):

I use this function in all of my macros that require a paste operation (sometimes paste is too quick and the pc can't copy the selection in time resulting in an error):

```
Function Wait(ByVal Seconds As Single)
    Dim CurrentTimer As Variant
    CurrentTimer = Timer
    Do While Timer < CurrentTimer + Seconds
    Loop
End Function
```

Then apply the following right before any "Selection.Paste" or "Selection.PasteSpecial":

```
Application.Excel.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
```

You may also have to enable the "ExcelPlugInShell 1.0 Type Library" found in Tools > References to get this to function properly as this uses language not available in MS Word by default.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
   Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 0
   Dim errorCode As Integer

   errorCode = wsh.Run("timeout 5", windowStyle, waitOnReturn)
```

this code allows to run cmd command and wait until execution is finished, in this particular case I am running command "timeout 5" which simly wait 5 seconds. 
I've found documentation [here](https://www.vbsedit.com/html/6f28899c-d653-4555-8a59-49640b0e32ea.asp)

Comment: explanation has been added

Answer (score 0):

Today I faced this problem and none of the proposed solutions worked, maybe because I'm using Microsoft Word for Mac.

So I created mine.

```
Function PauseSeconds(Seconds As Integer)
Dim PauseTime, Start
    PauseTime = Seconds
    Start = Timer
    Do While Timer < Start + PauseTime
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Function
```

Hope it works for other people as well.