# Publisher VBA MailMerge - Converting to PDF

Tags: vba, pdf, mailmerge, publisher

I have Publisher document with MailMerge records. My goal is to convert each page with each record to separate PDF document.

I have written this code. It generates PDF files with correct names, but for some reason PDFs contain only the second record from MailMerge.

```
Sub MailMerge()

Dim Lot As MailMergeDataField
Dim Price As MailMergeDataField
Dim Street As MailMergeDataField
Dim i As Long

Dim MainDoc As Document
Set MainDoc = ActiveDocument

With MainDoc
    For i = 1 To .MailMerge.DataSource.RecordCount
        With .MailMerge
            .SuppressBlankLines = True
             With .DataSource
                .FirstRecord = i
                .LastRecord = i
                .ActiveRecord = i
                Set Lot = .DataFields.Item("Lot")
                Set Price = .DataFields.Item("Price")
                Set Street = .DataFields.Item("Street")
                ThisDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat pbFixedFormatTypePDF, Lot.Value & "-" & Street.Value & ".pdf"
            End With
            .Execute Pause:=False, Destination:=pbMergeToNewPublication
        End With
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

I guess it needs a little change and everything will work fine, but I can't find out the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've stumbled into the same problem. I've came up with a sketchy workaround, but it works for me.

The main idea is to create a new '.pub'-file and perform the MailMerge with this file as the destination. After this, it is possible to export the separate PDF's, based on the page numbers from the initial document.

I had some problems with merging large files. That's why I built in the sleep function (based on this thread: [There is no Wait Method associated with Application in VisualBasic Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50957565/there-is-no-wait-method-associated-with-application-in-visualbasic-word/50958119))

Hopefully it helps!

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Sub Export_to_seperate_PDFs()


' Variables for MailMerge
Dim naam As MailMergeDataField
Dim i As Long

' Variables for This Document
Dim MainDoc As Document
Dim PathName As String
Dim FileName As String
Set MainDoc = ActiveDocument
PathName = MainDoc.Path
FileName = MainDoc.Name
Npages = MainDoc.Pages.Count
Debug.Print Npages

' Make a new Document called empty.pub in the same directory
Dim NewAppPub As New Publisher.Application
Set AppPub = New Publisher.Application
Set DocPub = AppPub.NewDocument
AppPub.ActiveWindow.Visible = True
DocPub.SaveAs FileName:=PathName & "empty.pub"
AppPub.ActiveDocument.Close

' Perform MailMerge
MainDoc.MailMerge.Execute Pause:=False, Destination:=3, _
FileName:=PathName & "empty.pub"

' try to close any other open publications (this does not seem to work yet)
Dim objDocument As Document
For Each objDocument In Documents
    Debug.Print objDocument.Name
    If objDocument.Name = "empty.pub" Then
        objDocument.SaveAs FileName:=PathName & "empty.pub"
        objDocument.Close
    ElseIf Not objDocument.Name = FileName Then
        objDocument.Close
    End If
Next objDocument

' Let the application wait for a couple of seconds
' in order to prevent errors on opening large files
Sleep 15000
NewAppPub.Open FileName:=PathName & "empty.pub"

' Loop through the records and save seperate PDFs'
With MainDoc
    For i = 1 To .MailMerge.DataSource.RecordCount
        With .MailMerge
            .SuppressBlankLines = False
            With .DataSource
                .FirstRecord = i
                .LastRecord = i
                .ActiveRecord = i
                Set naam = .DataFields.Item("Name")
                Debug.Print naam.Value
                
                ' Export publication to PDF based on page numbers
                NewAppPub.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat pbFixedFormatTypePDF, _
                PathName & naam.Value & ".pdf", _
                From:=((i - 1) * Npages) + 2, _
                To:=i * Npages + 1
                
            End With
        End With
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```